# I am unable to determine why my flag (of Very Low Quality Post) was disputed

Tags: discussion, support, disputed-flags

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33729411/phpmyadmin-configuration-storage-is-not-completely-configured

This is not even a question.  I flagged it as "Very Low Quality".  It is marked as "Disputed"

What does this mean ?  Can I see who disputed it and why.  How can I learn from this if it is all a secret ?

More importantly, why has this post not been deleted yet ?

Comment: I believe your flag was disputed because some of the reviewers decided that the question can be improved http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/10243210

Comment: @vaultah ...and originally in http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/10215636... So yes - the system automatically then "disputes" the flag

Comment: How did you find it in Triage ?  That brings me to the other point.  Far too many reviewers think that "Requires Editing" means the OP has to edit it.  There are so many of these in the Help and Improvement queue that can not be edited by us.  The OP has to edit them.  And the only choice I have is to mark them as Low Quality (or Skip but that's dodging the issue).

Comment: I would just downvote the question

Comment: Very Low Quality, especially on questions, is really for questions that are incomprehensible jibberish, which this question is not.  Flagging as "should be closed" and selecting the appropriate reason is usually the correct action for just run of the mill bad questions.

Comment: Somewhat inevitably, an SO user that doesn't think that clawing through the awfulness collected in the triage queue is a waste of his free time also has a biased view on what is possible.  Their glass is always half-full.  Or they just race through it.  Best thing to do is just not leave it up to somebody else to get the job done.  DV and CV bad questions.